# Rotation and resizing in LiveCode

Tags: rotation, resize, livecode

1)  How can I rotate fields, buttons to be able to write a text from up to down.

2)  I have a stack. Its width is 1622 and height is 588. How could I resize the stack to A4 with saving positions of my objects? My goal is to print it out in this size.

Thanks so much in advance for your help.

Comment: Please clarify question 2. Do you mean you want the user to be able to resize the stack, or do you want to simply print out the contents of the stack as is, but formatted for A4?

Comment: I want to simply print out the contents of the stack as is, but formatted for A4. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) Text rotation (rotation of fields and buttons) is not supported in LiveCode. Some developers have simulated this by taking a snapshot of the object, hiding it, then rotating the snapshot. See the dictionary for `import snapshot`.

```
import snapshot from field "foo" with effects
set the name of it to "fooimage"
rotate image "fooimage" by -90
```

Answer (score 0):

2) I wouldn't bother resizing the stack just for printing. Instead, create a substack, call it something like mystack_printing_A4. Lay out that stack exactly how you want for printing, including size, orientation, and positioning of objects. When you want to print, copy all of the contents of each object in your original stack to the corresponding object in your printing stack. Then use the `print card` command to print the preformatted card.

```
print card 1 of stack "mystack_printing_A4"
```

You never have to show the user the printing stack unless you want to show it as a print preview.